# jQuery working only in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, magento

I have this page: http://www.justdoors.co/plinths/bella-matching-plinth.html

And the following code to over-ride the css classes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
        jQuery('div.product-options-container:not(:eq(0))').css('height', '34px !important');
        jQuery('div.product-options-container:not(:eq(0))').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        jQuery('div.product-options-title:not(:eq(0))').css('padding', '15px 0 5px 10px !important');       
        jQuery('div.product-options-chooser:not(:eq(0))').css('width', '290px !important');
        });
</script>
```

The scripting works fine in Chrome but doesn't appear to work in other browsers, what am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried activating developer tools on any of the other respective browsers (FireBug for Firefox, Dragonfly for Opera, developer tools for IE)? They should be able to pinpoint any javascript errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was working but being overwritten by another function. Have fixed the issue now by adding an instance number to the divisions and adding in CSS specific for the division rather than trying to override.